# what is the difference between invariance and polygon offset in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es

what is the difference between invariance and polygon offset in OpenGL. I am getting confused with both. Since both are related to  low precession problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "invariance"? Invariance doesn't have anything to do with precision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replay @NicolBolas We do have a keyword invariant in opengl es 2.0. It is used to maintain then same precession of the output from vertex shaders(varying variable) over repeated call.

Answer (score 2):

From the GLES 2.0 spec:

> [...] variance refers to the possibility of getting different values
>   from the same expression in different shaders. For example, say two
>   vertex shaders each set gl_Position with the same expression in both
>   shaders, and the input values into that expression are the same when
>   both shaders run.
>
> It is possible, due to independent compilation of the two shaders,
>   that the values assigned to gl_Position are not exactly the same when
>   the two shaders run. In this example, this can cause problems with
>   alignment of geometry in a multi-pass algorithm. In general, such
>   variance between shaders is allowed. To prevent variance, variables
>   can be declared to be invariant, either individually or with a global
>   setting.

In other words, invariant is a mechanism provided by gles for you (the programmer) to tell the implementation that when a certain shader code is compiled, the gpu code generated must be the same **every time**.

Polygon offset is, ummm, completely unrelated. I refer you to the official FAQ https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm